# Angular to set page loading spiner always loading

Tags: angular, spinner, antd, ng-zorro-antd

Im using my angular project for the **[ant design ng zorro loding spin](https://ng.ant.design/components/spin/en)**, when i added to my angular page for the loading spin, its always loading, any one know to how to added correctly this loading

Thanks

**[here the stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ecppsx)**

**code here**

```
<div class="">
    <nz-spin nzSimple *ngIf="loading" ></nz-spin>
  </div>
    
<nz-table #basicTable [nzData]="listOfData">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of basicTable.data">
          <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.age }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
          <td>
            <a>Action 一 {{ data.name }}</a>
            <nz-divider nzType="vertical"></nz-divider>
            <a>Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>


  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .example {
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 30px 50px;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }
    `
  ]
})
```

**.ts**

```
  export class NzDemoSpinInsideComponent {
     loading = true;
    
    
    listOfData: Person[] = [
        {
          key: '1',
          name: 'John Brown',
          age: 32,
          address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park'
        },
        {
          key: '2',
          name: 'Jim Green',
          age: 42,
          address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park'
        },
        {
          key: '3',
          name: 'Joe Black',
          age: 32,
          address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park'
        }
      ];
    
      open(): void {
        this.visible = true;
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: `loading` is set as `true` and you didnt set it as `false`

Comment: If you want to show loader globally on api request then go through the post - https://medium.com/@imdurgeshpal/show-loader-spinner-on-http-request-in-angular-using-interceptor-68f57a9557a4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loading spinner is shown because of "loading" is true. Where you set it to false?

In Angular you can create a stream to load the data and use the async pipe in template for loading data. With ng-template you can show the loading spinner

```
<ng-template #loadingSpinner><nz-spin nzSimple></nz-spin></ng-template>

<div *ngIf="myStream | async as myData; else loadingSpinner> ... table ...</div>
```